# Styling the same div in two slightly different ways on the same page

Tags: css

I'm very new to CSS so forgive me if the answer to this is painfully obvious. I've been doing a good bit of searching and haven't found a solution yet.

I have a page with a signup div, controlled width, fully styled by CSS, floating right with text to the left. This is at the top of the page.

I'd like to have the same signup div appear again at the bottom of the page. However, this time, I'd like to be much wider. I've tried copying and pasting the HTML code (and the corresponding CSS code), slightly modifying the div names to essentially create a version 2 with my width modification, but that didn't work.

Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Comment: please post some code!

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a duplicate of your `div` at the bottom of your page with different `width` compared to the other one?
Then try adding 2 classes. One for `common styles` and the other for `specific styles`

**CSS:**

```
.signupDIv
{
   //common style
}

.topDiv
{
  width: 100px;
}

.bottomDIv
{
 width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="signupDIv topDiv"> //this is your original div
<div class="signupDIv bottomDIv"> // this is your duplicate div at the bottom with customized width
```

the `signupDIv` class is for your ***common styles*** such as `background-color`, etc. While the `topDiv` and `bottomDiv` is for your ***specific styles*** which in your case, is the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you modify the div 'names'? Did you add an id selector to each div? One of your divs could look like this:

```
    <div id="widesignup"> /*content*/ </div>
```

And the other could look like this.

```
    <div id="signup"> /*content*/ </div>
```

You would call on this id by posting this in you css:

```
    #widesignup {
        /*css*/
    }

     #signup {
        /*css*/
    }
```

Hope that helped.